# How to add a jar to the server lib for *embedded* JBoss?

Tags: jboss, seam, embedded-jboss

I need to add a crypto provider to the embedded JBoss used by Seam for integration tests.

For the regular JBoss it's a simple matter, just drop the files into the /lib folder of the server instance. With the embedded JBoss, however, things seem to be different. I've tried putting the jars in /embedded-jboss/bootstrap/lib and /embedded-jboss but no change, the classes are not seen.

I've read http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EmbeddedAndJavaSE and also looked in the source of org.jboss.embedded.Bootstrap but I haven't found a way yet. The build is done with Maven if it matters.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in the meantime: they can be added to the classpath of the plugin that runs the tests, like below. Works for me.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <!-- snip -->
        <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>add/here/your/jar</additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>
```